# How to pass unusual arguments to Python script using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have tried using argparse module of Python. I have a special requirement where the argument that I want pass to my Python script will be of below nature :

1. two arguments with same name, one will start with a '+' sign another with '-' sign. Each will have different significance and separate handling inside the script. For example (+p and -p) as below:

   myscript +p music,audio -p application
2. an argument which will take other arguments starting with '-' as its value and its end will be denoted in a sepcial manner, as below :

   myscript -info -name andrew -place newyork -info-

In the above example -info can have values as '-name andrew -place newyork' and the -info- will denote the end of its value.

I tried to achieve it with argparse but was not successful. Only using sys.argv I could manage to pass them. Any help on how can I achieve it with argparse will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `argparse` uses '-' and '--' to identify flags (`optionals`), using that character in an argument to mean something else is awkward (if not impossible).  And there's nothing to like your use of '-info-'.  Don't try to use `argparse` if you have to keep fighting its conventions.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. two arguments with same name, one will start with a '+' sign another
>    with '-' sign. Each will have different significance and separate
>    handling inside the script. For example (+p and -p) as below:
>
>    myscript +p music,audio -p application

Just set `prefix_chars='-+'` when calling `argparse.ArgumentParser` then you can add separate arguments with  `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` for +p and -p. It's described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars).

While the second one can probably be done, I think it would be a bit complicated and confusing for the user.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at this https://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/argparse/index.html seems like I can not use this prefix_chars with other positional or other types of args. Because I may send some normal - args along with +p & -p. Also any hint on the second requirement of how it can be possibly done will be helpful.